# how to interpret the "soft" and "max" in the SoftMax regression?

Tags: machine-learning, softmax

I know the form of the softmax regression, but I am curious about why it has such a name? Or just for some historical reasons?

Answer (score 4):

The maximum of two numbers `max(x,y)` could have sharp corners / steep edges which sometimes is an unwanted property (e.g. if you want to compute gradients).

To soften the edges of `max(x,y)`, one can use a variant with **softer** edges: the softmax function. It's still a **max** function at its core (well, to be precise it's an approximation of it) but smoothed out.

If it's still unclear, [here's](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/13/soft-maximum/) a good read.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have a set of scalars `xi` and you want to calculate a weighted sum of them, giving a weight `wi` to each `xi` such that the weights sum up to 1 (like a discrete probability). One way to do it is to set `wi=exp(a*xi)` for some positive constant `a`, and then normalize the weights to one. If `a=0` you get just a regular sample average. On the other hand, for a very large value of `a` you get `max` operator, that is the weighted sum will be just the largest `xi`. Therefore, varying the value of `a` gives you a "soft", or a continues way to go from regular averaging to selecting the max. The functional form of this weighted average should look familiar to you if you already know what a SoftMax regression is.